# Как обновить состояние редюсера?

Tags: redux

Как можно обновить состояние редюсера такой вложенности:

```
const initialState = {

    filter_models: {

        adventure_state: null,

        type_id: null,

        bodies: [],

        brands: [],

        models: []

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Элементарно:

```
const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));

newState.filter_models.brands.push('Apple');

return newState;
```

Comment: Вроде `filter_models` будет одинаковым объектом и в старом `state` и в новом, поэтому мы изменим старый `state`, что нельзя делать, нет?

Comment: @diraria мы старый `state` не трогаем, копируем его в новый и меняем новый.

Comment: у нас копирование нечестное ведь, неглубокое (то есть [shallow-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy))?

Comment: @diraria согласен. обновил ответ.